# How to understand boxplot comparing performance metrics of machine learning models?

Tags: r, boxplot, machine-learning-model

I have created several models and plot their accuracy using a boxplot. What does the circles outside the box mean?

[image]

I used caret package for building the models and the following code to make a picture.

```
model_list <- list(rf = rf_model, gbm=gbm_model,  xgboost = xgboost_model, treebag = treebag_model)
 resamples <- resamples(model_list)
 bwplot(resamples, metric="Accuracy")
```

Comment: Those circles seem like the medians. Can you share the code that produced the plot with us? What function from what package have you used?

Comment: I think medians are black circles. I don't know what are white ones.

Comment: This basically means you did not pick good hyperparameters for `xgboost`. Or perhaps you did not tune the model for high accuracy? Imbalanced data set? The white circles are `outliers` - apparently some of the re-sample instances were much worse than the majority.

Comment: Most probably need to pick hyperparameters better, since I put accuracy as metric and balanced classes so that they are the same size.